# iOS UIActivity View Controller Opera Mini Button?

Tags: iphone, ios, web, opera, uiactivityviewcontroller

Does anyone know if there is a service that adds the option to open a URL in the opera mini app from an iOS UIactivity view controller. I have safari and chrome buttons but I am just trying to get the major iOS web browsers

For now I am just trying to open `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my understanding that Opera Mini's URL scheme is `ohttp://`, so you can just download [TUSafariActivity](https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity) from GitHub, change the images for the activity, and use `ohttp://www.google.com/` instead of `http://www.google.com/` in the activity's NSURL to open Google's home page in Opera Mini instead of Safari.

Opera Mini's url schemes include:

1. `ohttp://`
2. `ohttps://`
3. `oftp://`

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, can you look at [my other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438686/ios-uiactivity-view-controller-add-to-reading-list-button?rq=1)

Comment: For Opera Touch you should use:
`touch-http`
`touch-https`